# @Nonnull with different IDEs - warn about unnecessary null checks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, findbugs, jsr305

I'm working in an environment where developers use different IDEs - Eclipse, Netbeans and IntelliJ. I'm using the @Nonnull annotation (javax.annotation.Nonnull) to indicate that a method will never return null:

```
@Nonnull
public List<Bar> getBars() {
  return bars;  // this.bars is a final, initialized list
}
```

I'd like other developers to get a warning if they do one of the following:

1. Change the method to return null without removing the @Nonnull annotation
2. Unnecessarily check for null for methods that are explicitly defined with @Nonnull: if (foo.getBars() == null) { ... do something ... }

The first scenario is supported e.g. by IntelliJ. The second is not; the clients are not warned that checking for null is unnecessary.

We're in any case planning to move towards returning clones of collections instead of the collections themselves, so is it better to forget @Nonnull and do this instead:

```
public List<Bar> getBars() {
  return new ArrayList<Bar>(bars);
}
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, I'm not considering changing IDE's for this. I'd like to know whether what I described above is supported by the mentioned IDEs - or alternatively, if there is a good reason as to why it is not supported.

I get the point about not relying too much on contracts. However, if I write getBars() with the style in the last paragraph (return a clone of the list), then e.g. IntelliJ flags a warning for any code that does

```
if (foo.getBars() == null) { ... }
```

If you choose to follow this warning and remove the null check, you seem to be equally reliant on the getBars() implementation not changing. However, in this case you seem to be depending on implementation details instead of an explicit contract (as is the case with @Nonnull).

**Edit #2:**

I'm not concerned about execution speed, null checks are indeed very fast. I'm concerned about code readability. Consider the following:

Option A:

```
if ((foo.getBars() == null || foo.getBars().size() < MAXIMUM_BARS) && 
    (baz.getFoos() == null || baz.getFoos().size() < MAXIMUM_FOOS)) { 
  // do something
}
```

Option B:

```
if (foo.getBars().size() < MAXIMUM_BARS && 
    baz.getFoos().size() < MAXIMUM_FOOS) {
  // do something
}
```

I think Option B is more readable than Option A. Since code is read more often than it is written, I'd like to ensure all code I (and others in our team) write is as readable as possible.

Comment: If you want to do 2) you are very much depending on a third party to do what it promised and not change. Is that really what you want? Although is might be internal, I would prefer to be defensive and check for nulls if my code will break if some other code violates it's contract

Comment: I didn't catch the actual question - what do you want? I can't imagine you mean to move away from IntelliJ because it misses one possible diagnostic. Do you want IntelliJ to support this diagnostic? Submit a bug report if you think it should. Same thing is true for Eclipse and Netbeans. And what is that last paragraph about?

Comment: Well, you could create a utility method that covers the `null` case and go `Util.size(foo.getBars()) < MAXIMUM_BARS`.

Comment: @Thomas Since `getBars()` will never return `null` *by contract,* a utility method is unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidHarkness You are right, but the idea was to spare the programmer the effort of finding out whether `getBars()` can return `null` or not. In the worst case, the utility method may generate the (minimal) overhead of calling a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

- Stick with your `@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` annotations just like you are doing it already.
- Define and enforce a default. It doesn't really matter what the default is, but it should be the same across your entire code base.
- Use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to check for your cases 1 and 2. FindBugs has plugins for most IDEs, I saw Eclipse, Netbeans, and IntelliJ mentioned, but there are more. (The number 2 case is covered by the RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_OF_NONNULL_VALUE rule. I tested it. Just thought I should mention that after reading DavidHarkness' comment elsewhere on this page.)

This approach is IDE agnostic and works also in an external build environment like Hudson or Jenkins.

Comment: I feel this is the best answer so far, so I'm accepting it. I'll experiment with FindBugs to see if it indeed warns for case 2.

Comment: Tested again at work. With both Maven and the Eclipse plugin, FindBugs only generates a warning when using `!=` in the comparison--not when testing with equality as in the OP. I filed an [issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1248/) for it. Does using `nonNullValue == null` generate a warning for you?

Comment: @DavidHarkness [Here's a screenshot](http://i44.tinypic.com/vsde85.gif) of my Eclipse editor. The blue bug marker is an occurrence of RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_OF_NONNULL_VALUE.

Comment: Ah, I get the same indicator with that code, but it disappears if I remove `|| getBars().size() > 2`. I suspect the detector sees the null check as superfluous only because calling `size` on a `null` value will throw an exception anyway. It's not actually detecting that the reference itself cannot be `null`.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Ah, I see your point, same here. Thanks for finding this out and filing the issue. As for my answer, I still recommend the approach, even if we see that sometimes the bug detectors themselves can have bugs. :-) Overall, FindBugs does quite a good job at null pointer analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, with your annotation you want to do two things:

- make the program faster
- make the programmers have to work less (because they don't have to type the null-checks)

For the first one: A Null-check consumes hardly any resources. If you run this sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
        returnsNonNull(i);
        doNothing();
    }
    System.out.println("Without nullcheck took "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-ms)+" ms to complete");

    ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=10000;i<20000;i++) {
        if (returnsNonNull(i)!=null) {
            doNothing();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("With nullcheck took "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-ms)+" ms to complete");
}

public static String returnsNonNull(int i) {
    return "Foo "+i+" Bar";
}
public static void doNothing() {

}
```

You will see, there is hardly any difference between these two tests. The second one (with the null-check) is sometimes even faster than the first one, meaning they both are pretty much indistinguishable when it comes to resource use.

Now to the second point:
You are actually making the programmers work more, not less. Except if there are absolutely no functions in your whole project and framework that ever return null the programmer now has to look up the function each time to check if he has to do a null-check or not. Seeing that about every framework in Java can under some conditions return null in some functions you are not reducing the workload for your programmers.

You said you want a warning to appear when they do a null-check where it is not necessary because of your @Nonnull-annotation. So what they will do is they type out the whole null-check and then get a warning and have to remove it again. See what I mean?

Also what if you make a mistake in your code and mark something as @Nonnull that can return null?

What I'd do is write it into the Javadoc under @return. Then the programmer can decide what he does, which is usually better than forcing others to write code your style.

Comment: We use package-level annotations to mark *every* method return value, parameter, and field as `@Nonnull` by default because a lot of code is easier to reason about without nulls. Programmers must override it at the element level if they can't get away without using `null`. Combined with unit tests and FindBugs, this has saved countless headaches over the past year.

Comment: Also, beware of micro-benchmarks: the JVM and JIT can play with the bytecode, and you never know what else is taking up CPU cycles.

Comment: It is always better to have more formal information in the contract. Fuzzy contracts are never good.